# What is this bottle shown in "An American Tail"?

Tags: props, translation, an-american-tail

In *An American Tail*, one scene (at about 28:20) prominently features a bottle with Yiddish lettering on it:

[image]

and ten seconds later (mysteriously with a different font):

[image]

(My original guesses (תבצב״ת and כּייללעל) were close but wrong.)

```
תנצב״ה 
פייוועל
```

The `״` before the last letter of the first word indicates that it's an acronym.

I expect it's something mundane, but what *does* it say and mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**The soul of my lord shall be bound in the bundle of life**](https://www.wordsense.eu/%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%A6%D7%91%D7%B4%D7%94/) is what is written on the top part of the box according to wordsense.com.  It is a Hebrew acronym from 1 Samuel 25:29

[**fayvl**](https://www.wordsense.eu/%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%99%D7%95%D7%95%D7%9C/) Proper noun: a male given name, Feivel is what is written on the bottom part of the box according to wordsense.com.  It is Yiddish

Feivel's family assumed that he was dead as they have been searching for him for a long period of time.  His sister is imagining what his "tombstone" would say.